# C++ BEGINNER factorial program, confusing output

Tags: c++, factorial

I'm doing intro to C++ on MIT OCW and the following code is given in the professors first problem set as a basic program to calculate factorials, with a few related questions.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
int main () 
{
    short number;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;
    cout << "The factorial of " << number << " is ";
    int accumulator = 1;
    for(; number > 0; accumulator = (accumulator * (number--)));
    cout << accumulator << '.\n';
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

The first question is:
"What do you get when you enter the following values: 0, 1, 2, 9, 10?"

The answers section reads, "0: 1; 1: 1; 2: 2; 9: 362880; 10: 3628800," but that is not what happens for me.
My program outputs "11768" proceeding each apparently correct answer, and I have no idea why.

The answer set I see: "0: 111768; 1: 111768; 2: 211768; 9: 36288011768; 10: 362880011768"

Perhaps there's something wrong in the code, but I don't see it.
I am using Visual Studio 2012. Maybe someone has an idea? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change:

```
cout << accumulator << '.\n';
```

To:

```
cout << accumulator << ".\n";
```

The compiler is converting the multi-character literal `'.\n'` into the integer `11768`. This behavior is implementation defined.

Comment: Or `cout << accumulator << ".\n";`

Comment: @maditya, that's exactly what my answer says. What do you mean?

Comment: Apparently I've forgotten how to read. For some reason I thought you took out the `.`, and I proposed what I thought was an alternative solution. So here is technically the actual alternative: `cout << accumulator << '\n';`

Comment: you can also do std::cout << accumulator << "." << std::endl;

Comment: @lmedinas: There are people that suggest (and they have convinced me) that you should not use `std::endl` ever, as it involves a flush of the stream. If you only need a newline, use `<< '\n'`, if you also need to flush use `<< '\n' << std::flush;` to make it explicit in the code for other maintainers that you do want the `flush` there

Answer (score 2):

Probably should learn to use endl, or you will get confused by unflushed streams at some point. I know I have.  Not saying this is an unflushed stream problem, but OP would not have had this problem if he habitually used endl.